# awk or sed, move first column to end?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text file separated by space as follows. I need to re-arrange the columns so that the first column is at the end of each line.

I have an idea of how this could be done using `cut -d' ' f1` but I'm wondering if there is an easy way with `awk` or `sed`.

Text File:

```
™️       trade mark
ℹ️       information
↔️..↙️    left-right arrow..down-left arrow
↩️..↪️    right arrow curving left..left arrow curving right
⌚..⌛    watch..hourglass done
⌨️       keyboard
⏏️       eject button
⏩..⏳    fast-forward button..hourglass not done
⏸️..⏺️    pause button..record button
Ⓜ️       circled M
▪️..▫️    black small square..white small square
▶️       play button
◀️       reverse button
```

*Want symbol list to follow description instead.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `sed`

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) *\(.*\)/\2 \1/' infile
```

This `\([^ ]*\)` will match everything until a non-space characters seen.
The parentheses `\(...\)` is used to made a group matching which its index would be `\1`.

The `\(.*\)` matches everything after first group and it's indexed `\2`.
The  `*` in `\(...\) *\(...\)` out of matched groups will ignore to print in output which is matching spaces between group 1 and 2, you could use `\s*` (with GNU `sed`) or `[[:space:]]*` (standardly) instead to match any spacing characters instead of just ASCII SPC as well.

Then at the end first we are printing matched *group2* than *group1* with a space between.

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '{first = $1; $1=""; print $0, first}' file.txt
```

Store the first column in a variable, write blank to the first column, print the whole line (`$0$` is the whole line, now with the first column blanked) followed by the first column.

Comment: I had to move the last column to the beginning of the file and this worked perfectly. my code was `awk '{last = $32; $32=""; print last,$0}' oldfile.txt > newfile.txt`

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '{ printf "%s ",$NF;for (i=2;i<=NF-1;i++) { printf " %s",$i } printf "\n" }' filename
```

With awk, $NF will signify the last piece of data. Print this and then loop through the other fields from 2 to one but the last field, printing those.

Comment: Your answer could probably use a bit more explanation. It's quite a long, "complex" `awk`, and many people aren't that comfortable with `awk`. A bit more explanation would help non-`awk`ers

Answer (score 3):

With Perl:

```
perl -pe 's/(\S+)(\s+)(.*)/$3$2$1/' file
```

---

`(\S+)` captures all non-whitespace character from the beginning

`(\s+)` capture all whitespace following the captured characters

`(.*)` capture everything else until the end of the line

`$3$2$1` reverses the 3 matched patterns